# And/Or between Filter Arrays

Tags: javascript, sapui5

So I have two filter arrays, and instead of just concatinating and letting UI5 select/group the respective properties with and/or operator, I want to perform an AND between both the filter arrays.

I tried passing both filter arrays, and adding and. But it doesnt work.

```
var kFilter = new Filter({
  filters: [
    dFilters,
    bFilters
  ],
  and: true
});
```

Comment: are you sure dFilters and bFilters are filter-objects aswell? common mistake is that at least one of them is an array instead of a filter-object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var aFilter = [];
var aOrFilter = [];
var aAndFilter = [];

//Create filter array for OR condition
aOrFilter[
    new sap.ui.model.Filter("Property1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, sValue),
    new sap.ui.model.Filter("Property2", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, sValue)
];

//Create filter array for AND condition
aAndFilter[
  new sap.ui.model.Filter("Property3", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, sValue),
  new sap.ui.model.Filter("Property4", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, sValue)
];

//Concatinating both filter arrays with AND condition
aFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter([
    new sap.ui.model.Filter(aOrFilter, false), //Filters get OR codition
    new sap.ui.model.Filter(aAndFilter, true) //Filters get AND condition
], true); //Concatinating both with AND condition
```

Result:

```
(Property1 EQ "XXX" OR Property2 EQ "XXX") AND (Property3 EQ "XXX" AND Property4 EQ "XXX")
```